# How to Sort PriorityQueue in Java with class

Tags: java, priority-queue

I know there are lots of answers about this problem. I tried following it but it wont show the result that I want.
there is an

**input**
60 3
50 2
20 1
40 2
30 3
30 1

and I'm expecting the 
**output**
60 3
50 2
40 2
30 3
30 1
20 1

but if i print the priorityQueue it will show

60 3
50 2
40 2
20 1
30 3
30 1

I dont' knwo why..

This is my code below

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MaximumIncomeSchedule {
    static class Schedule  {
        int income;
        int date;

        public Schedule(int i, int d) {
            income = i;
            date = d;
        }
       
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        PriorityQueue<Schedule> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(n,(o1, o2) -> {
            if(o2.income==o1.income)
                return o2.date - o1.date;
            return o2.income - o1.income;
        });
        int mD = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int M = sc.nextInt();
            int D = sc.nextInt();
            Schedule s = new Schedule(M, D);
            pq.add(s);
            mD = Math.max(mD, D);
        }
        for (Schedule s : pq) {
            System.out.println("income:" + s.income + " " + "time: " + s.date);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `PriorityQueue` class uses a heap as its implementation. A heap does not know the total ordering of its elements, only what the _next_ element is. Iterating the queue cannot give the elements in order (except by coincidence). The only way to get the elements in order is to repeatedly poll the queue.

Comment: thx kriegaex! I think I missed the important point!! helped alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator lambda is correct, you can use it as-is. You just need to poll the queue in order to fetch the elements in the correct order:

```java
    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
      Schedule s = pq.poll();
      System.out.println("income:" + s.income + " " + "time: " + s.date);
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, I just noticed the comment by @Unmitigated after posting and followed the link. The answer to the linked question is basically the same as mine. I am going to vote closing this question as a duplicate. Here it is about iterating, not about `toString()`, but it is a duplicate with regard to the solution.